# nextProps always identical to this.props in componentWillReceiveProps, even when the props have changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a component in my React app that renders a total value for the user. When that value goes up, I want to play a noise. I figured that within the component that displays the total would be a good place to play that noise from.

So I added a `componentWillReceiveProps` method to the component, and in it, I calculate two totals: `total` is calculated from `this.props` and `nextTotal` is calculated from `nextProps`.

To my surprise, even when the values change, and the totals change, `nextTotal` and `total` are *always* the same. So the conditional that I want firing when the total goes up never happens.

I wrote up a simple, single-component example. [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydaso4cs/).

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    var total = 0;
    this.props.vals.forEach(val => total+= val);

    var nextTotal = 0;
    nextProps.vals.forEach(val => nextTotal+= val);

        console.log(total, nextTotal)

    if (nextTotal > total) {
            //never runs
            console.log('moving up');
        }
  },
  render: function() {
    var total = 0;
    vals.forEach(val => total+= val)
    return (
        <div>{total}</div>
    )
  }
});

var vals = [1, 21, 452, 123];

setInterval(renderReact, 1000)

function renderReact() {
    vals.push(10);
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello
      vals={vals}
    />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
}
```

As you can see, every second it adds 10 to the `vals` array, which means the total moves up by 1. But if you open the console, you can see that `total` and `nextTotal` are always the same, and `moving up` never gets logged.

I'm clearly misunderstanding *something*, and if anyone could explain what my misunderstanding is, and how I should achieve what I'm going for, that would be fantastic.

Comment: why not try logging the two arrays? check it out you keep pushing ten to both of them...https://jsfiddle.net/ydaso4cs/2/ which are the same thing...

Comment: You are passing the array directly to the element. `this.props.vals` and `nextProps.vals` are referencing the same object.

Comment: not only are you referencing the same array, your component isnt updating since you are calling the render once. I dont see any code that is causing an update.

Comment: @JohnRuddell there is a setInterval that is calling renderReact every second

Comment: Perhaps reading this will help: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html

Comment: ah my bad I thought I read setTimeout. the array reference is the issue though

Comment: try adding a new variable like so `let valsCopy = vals.slice(); valsCopy.push(10); ` and then in the return `vals={valsCopy}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As noted in the comments (by @PitaJ), your problem is that you're passing in an array the first time, and then ALTERING the array - rather than calling with a new property. You've reached into the object your component is holding a reference to as its existing property and changed the contents of it.

In your fiddle, try this:

```
function renderReact() {
    vals.push(10);
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello
      vals={vals.concat([])}
    />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
}
```

Passing a copy of the array in as your prop each time, you'll see they differ appropriately.

This is actually a non-trivial source of error in using react, and can crop up even when using redux with it if reducers aren't carefully written. Using immutable data structures is one way to avoid it.